# Ruby attr_accessor (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby, class, attributes

I'm trying to do class attributes, here's what I have:

```
class Base
  class << self
    attr_accessor :coll
  end
end

class Post < Base
  coll :posts
end
```

I'm getting an error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly? attr_accessor creates 2 methods, in your example: Base.coll and Base.coll= , so something like this would work:

```
class Base
  class << self
    attr_accessor :coll
  end
end

class Post < Base
  self.coll = :posts
  puts coll.inspect #=> :posts
end
```

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the concept. Thanks.

Comment: You are creating a local variable named `coll` which shadows the getter method. Neither the setter nor the getter is ever called.

Comment: So I guess I need to replace coll = :posts with self.coll = :posts ?